# how to return random sampling of data from hash

Tags: ruby, hash, sinatra, erb, openstruct

I've parsed a json file (which consists of a single array called "items" containing 4 key-value pairs) into an OpenStruct so that I can treat my data as if they were objects. I would now like to display each object at random on a web page.

```
# read json file and parse into OpenStruct
def read_json(url)
    json_file = File.read(url)
    json_obj = JSON.parse(json_file, object_class: OpenStruct)
    return json_obj
end

# sample array
def random_display(json)
    out = json.items.sample
    return out
end
```

My json is basically like:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "foo": "bar"
        },
}
```

And then finally in my Sinatra routes, I've got:

```
get '/' do
  @data = read_json("public/data.json")
  @random = random_display(@data)
  erb :index
end
```

In my erb page I'm using `<%= @random %>` and getting a simple `#` as the result. Why? I mean, I'm aware that it's because I'm not telling it to show the value of any one particular key. But how do I work around that?

Another thing - I feel like the way I'm going about what I'm trying to do (which is create a little game that asks you to pick the more expensive of two random options) - is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Try escaping it: `<%= h(@random) %>`

Comment: Did this and got "undefined method 'h'"

Comment: Look at the raw source of your page HTML. You need to HTML escape that somehow, so whatever method does that job is the one you use here. I thought `h` was built-in to ERB but I must be wrong.

Comment: Hm, okay. So Inspector shows a random openstruct object each time I refresh the page, but the only thing showing in the browser window is the "#". h is the escaping character for Rails - in erb it's adding another `%` so that your variable looks like this: `<%%= @random %>`. That, however, removes the openstruct object from Inspector completely, and prints `<%= @random %> to the page instead of the #.

Comment: Then you need to follow the [recommendations in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123586/how-do-i-html-escape-text-data-in-a-sinatra-app).